# How to change date format in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

how to change the date time format 2011-09-01 09:39:23 to 2011-Aug-01 09:39:23 in asp.net

I am using this DateTime.Now; to get the date time but I want it in 2011-Aug-01 09:39:23 format, how to do that

I set datetime as 
string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

both did not work

```
 param[1] = new MySqlParameter("@Created", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
        param[1].Value = now;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Created", now);
        param[2] = new MySqlParameter("@Modified", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
        param[2].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modified", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#Y100) useful

More specifically, you want:

```
yourDate.toString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss");

Answer (score 2):

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    txtrcptdate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss ");
}
```